# Drone in Russia

Tags: russia, regulations, drones

Can I bring 249g drone to Russia and fly without any registration ?

According my research I can, but very currious about real life experiences.

Thank you

Comment: Don’t think this is on topic here. Aviation.SE maybe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not specific to travel.

Comment: No, I consider it a valid question. Drone now are like photo camera: used for travel documentation, and we all had question in past about films (through security, use on foreign countries, what one should never make photos). In any case: it depends where in Russia, and your nationality. Less touristic: more troubles (really much more).

Comment: I go out of tourist places at all (Yakutia), so I believe that as long as I can enter the country with drone, the rest will be just about luck. Thank you

Comment: Considering the other drone questions in this Travel section, I don't see mine off topic. Also drone is camera, which belongs to travel. If I ask how much weight can drone carry, I ask in Aviation section. Thank you for replying to the topic. You help the others too

Answer (score 3):

After a month of flying in the coldest places on Earth I must say that flying is not a problem outside of the cities. 
Most places in Russia are far abandoned, so seeing any authorities is almost impossible.
However, once you encounter with police, they will most likely make you troubles since you might look like spy.
Good knowledge of Russian language and negotiations can make you out of it